# Получение последнего дня месяца по его номеру

Tags: php

Как по номеру месяца получить его последний день? Написал такой код:

```
$m = 10;
$unixtime = time("2017-$m-01 01:01:01");
print date('t', $unixtime);
```

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: почему не работает мой код?

Comment: работает https://ideone.com/WyJVIx

Comment: Потому, что не `time`, а `strtotime`

Comment: @Jean-Claude а теперь поставьте там месяц равным 2

Answer (score 3):

```
$m = 06;
$unixtime = strtotime("2017-$m-01 01:01:01");
print date('t', $unixtime);
```

Comment: спасибо всем разобрался

Comment: @bot так примите ответ